# Напишите рекурсивную функцию, которая осуществляет суммирование чисел в списке. Выводит ошибку!

Tags: python, python-3.x

Напишите рекурсивную функцию, которая осуществляет суммирование чисел в списке. Список должен быть сгенерирован из 10 чисел, каждое в диапазоне от 1 до 100.

```
import random

def Summa(n, Massiv, sum = 0):
      if n == 1: return sum
      sum += Massiv[n-1]
      return Summa(n-1, Massiv, sum)

def massiv_generator():
      m = []
      for i in range(10):
            m += random.randrange(1, 101)
      return m

m = massiv_generator()
n = len(m)
sum = Summa(n, m)
print("Результат",sum)
```

Comment: И не называйте свои переменные так же, как встроенные функции питона. `sum` - встроенная функция, вы её перекрываете своей переменной.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача, конечно, бесcмысленная:

```py
>>> def summ(nums, i=0):
...     return nums[i] + summ(nums, i + 1) if i < len(nums) - 1 else nums[i]
... 
>>> summ([1,3,5])
9
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

Тут вы пытаетесь к массиву **прибавить** число, такая запись само собой не является валидной. Чтобы **добавить** число в массив, существует метод `[].append()`

так что просто
замените

```
 m += random.randrange(1, 101)
```

на

```
  m.append(random.randrange(1, 101))
```

Comment: Или `m += [random.randrange(1, 101)]`, т.е. добавить к списку список с одним элементом.

Comment: @MarianD Этот метод всё же хуже, потому что создаёт новый список, в отличие от `.append`

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, вы прав, я только хотел показать другой подход.

Answer (score 1):

укороченный вариант:

```
def summ(m):
    return m.pop() + summ(m) if m else 0
```